# Compile BlueZ for iOS7?

Tags: c++, ios, bluetooth, cross-compiling, bluez

I am currently trying to create a PAN on a jailbroken iOS device (iPad, in this case). On my Raspberry Pi I can achieve this using the bluez bluetooth stack and the pan daemon that comes with it. I thought if it could be possible to port bluez to the iOS device, unfortunately I don't really know enough about compiling - besides compiling stuff using a makefile I didn't do much in that regard.

I was able to get a gcc compiler onto the iPad using BigBoss's "installsdk3", but if I try to run `configure` on bluez it gives me `Compiler cannot create executables`.

Does anybody know if this is possible, how or can give me directions how this could be achieved? I know that xcode on the mac comes with a c++ compiler for iOS, but I couldn't really find out how to get the makefile to make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluez is specifically a Linux bluetooth stack. OS X and iOS are based on BSD which though similar to Linux is not the same. I very much doubt you can run bluez on iOS.

Instead look into Apple's own bluetooth stack.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Comment: thank you. I guess technically I don't even need bluez, the only thing I need is the `pand` that comes with it, since I can't find a  way to create/join a PAN with what apple provides. Any chance getting `pand` to run?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not an expert on Apple things, all i can tell you is that bluez and things that interact with it (like pand) will not work on a non-linux system.

Answer (score 1):

BlueZ is the user mode part of the Bluetooth stack. It depends on a kernel mode component, which exists in the Linux kernel but not BSD (as mentioned in other answers, what Mac OS is based on). Hence BlueZ cannot work with a Mac OS kernel.

AFAIK, there is no way to run Mac OS with a Linux kernel.